# Contraposition followed by universal conditionals

Tags: logic

In the page of Contraposition,Wikipedia has the following claim:

*Strictly speaking, a contraposition can only exist in two simple conditionals. However, a contraposition may also exist in two complex, universal conditionals, if they are similar. Thus, ${\displaystyle \forall {x}(P{x}\to Q{x})}$, or "All $Ps$ are $Qs$," is contraposed to ${\displaystyle \forall {x}(\neg Q{x}\to \neg P{x})}$, or "All non-$Qs$ are non-$Ps$.*

---

I know that for the two propositions $P,Q$ :

$$P \implies Q ≡¬Q \implies ¬P$$

The proof is as follows:

$$P \implies Q $$
$$≡¬P \lor Q $$
$$≡¬¬Q \lor ¬P$$
$$≡¬Q \implies ¬P$$

However I still don't know how to prove the other form of contraposition followed by universal conditionals,does there exist anyway to prove that with elementary knowledge about logic?

Comment: It should suffice that if $R\equiv S$ then $\forall x. R\equiv \forall x. S$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use universal generalization from $P(x)\implies Q(x)$, provided that $P(x)\implies Q(x)$ is provable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof for the first-order logic equivalence of $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ and $\forall x (\neg Q(x) \to \neg P(x))$ is definitely a good bit tricker than that for the propositional logic equivalence of  $P \to Q$ and $\neg Q \to \neg P$

To show the first-ordwr logic equivalence, we can do several things:

First, we can employ the *formal semantics* for first-order logic: this is kind of like what truth-tables do for propositional logic, but in first-order logic you cannot use truth-tables since there are infinitely many possible worlds to consider, so things get more complicated here, and indeed I will not flesh that all out; it definitely goes beyond an 'elementary knowledge' of logic.

However, using that semantics, you can obtain some important results:

First, it allows us to extend the notion of equivalence from sentences to formulas. Hmmm, what do I mean by this?

Well, a *sentence* is something like $P \to Q$, while a *formula* is something like $P(x) \to Q(x)$.

A sentence is actually a very special kind of formula: it is a formula to which you can assign a truth-value. That is, once you know the truth-values of $P$ and $Q$, you also know the truth-value of $P \to Q$.

However, note that we cannot assign a truth-value to a formula like $P(x) \to Q(x)$: note that this formula can occur in a statement like $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$, but also in a statement like $\exists x (P(x) \to Q(x))$, and those two statements can have different truth-values ... which is why $P(x) \to Q(x)$ doesn't have any truth-value at all: it is not a claim, statement, or sentence ... it is merely a formula that can be *part* of a sentence.

Still, we *can* say that the formulas $P(x) \to Q(x)$ and $\neg Q(x) \to \neg P(x)$ are equivalent. Again, there is a technical definition for this, and again it is beyond 'elementary understanding' to flesh the details, but I think you can see that these formulas are equivalent in some intuitive sense.

In fact, it turns out that you can extend the very same propositional equivalence principles from propositional logic (Commutation, Double Negation, DeMorgan, etc) to first-order logic formulas, even if they are not sentences. So, you could take your proof, fill in $P(x)$ for $P$, and $Q(x)$ for $Q$, and now you have a proof that $P(x) \to Q(x)$ and $\neg Q(x) \to \neg P(x)$ are equivalent formulas.

OK, one more ingredient, and we're there. Your proof was actually a little quick, but when you went from $\neg P \lor Q$ to $\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P$, you presumably first went from $\neg P \lor Q$ to $Q \lor \neg P$ using Commutation, and from there to $\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P$ by Double Negation.

But note: the Double Negation principle really only says that for any statement $\phi$ we have that $\phi$ and $\neg \neg \phi$ are equivalent .... and $\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P$ is not the double negation of $Q \lor \neg P$ ... for that would be $\neg \neg (Q \lor \neg P)$ ... So ... why exactly is it then that we can say that $Q \lor \neg P$ and $\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P$ are equivalent?

Well, fortunately you can show (again, I'll omit technical details) that if two statements $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent, then the result of substituting $\psi$ for any $\phi$ in a *larger* statement will be equivalent to the original. This  general principle is called the Substitution Principle for logically equivalent statements.

As an example: since by Double Negation we know that $Q$ is equivalent to $\neg \neg Q$, by the Substitution Principle it is now also the case that $Q \lor \neg P$ is equivalent to $\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P$.

Moreover, we can once again we can extend this Substitution Principle to formulas in general.

Ok, and now we have all the basic ingredients:

First, we have that $P(x) \to Q(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\neg Q(x) \to \neg P(x)$

Second, we can use the Substitution Principle to apply this to a larger formula, and therefore $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x (\neg Q(x) \to \neg P(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\forall x~(Px\to Qx)$.

Take any $x$. Thus by universal instantiation, $Px\to Qx$ holds.  You have already shown this is equivalent to $\neg Qx\to\neg Px$.

Since that holds for any $x$, therefore we can generalise. Thus $\forall x~(\neg Qx\to\neg Px)$ is derived from the assumption. $$\forall x~(Px\to Qx) \implies \forall x~(\neg Qx\to\neg Px)$$

The converse can be proven similarly.

$$\forall x~(Px\to Qx) \impliedby \forall x~(\neg Qx\to\neg Px)$$

... and therefore we have established the equivalence.

$$\forall x~(Px\to Qx) \iff \forall x~(\neg Qx\to\neg Px)$$